# Center button and text issues HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make a `onClick()` button that when pressed, makes text show. My issue is that when I click the button, the button scoots down when the text shows up.

Is there a way to make the button not move when the text appears? Maybe make it actually be there but hidden and on button unhide it? I don't know, I just don't want it to move when the button is pressed.

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic'])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.flip = function() {
      $scope.coinResult = "Heads";
    }
})
```

```html
<body ng-app="starter">
    <head>
        <style>
            .button-calm {
                width: 50%;
            }
            .coin-result {
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 100px;
            }
            .centerItems {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="centerItems">
            <p class="coin-result" ng-bind="coinResult"></p>
            <button class="button button-outline button-calm" ng-click="flip()">Flip!</button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to fix the height of the text div `coin-result` and give it `overflow-y: auto`. This ensures that the button stays put.

Demo below:

```css
.button-calm {
  width: 50%;
}
.coin-result {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.centerItems {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerItems">
  <p class="coin-result" ng-bind="coinResult">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
  <button class="button button-outline button-calm" ng-click="flip()">Flip!</button>
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!